# How to avoid pandas to not convert null values from utf8 to string when using to_sql?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, unicode, null

I have some excel data files which I want to import in a MySQL database. I've created a script to do so with pandas (read_excel), and because i got accents and other specials characters, i must encode the data read by pandas in utf8 with .str.encode() (and my MySQL database is utf8). The issue is when I import the data into the DB with to_sql(), pandas convert all null values (NaN, NaT, Null, ...) to string ...

I've tried many encodings. I've tried to replace the null values with fillna(), and also replace them to None, i've also set mysql to avoid invalid values (STRICT_TRANS MODE et NO_ZERO_DATE for NaT)

```
for y in range(0,len(FICHIERS)):
DONNEES[FICHIERS[y].split('.')[0]] = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(APPLICATION_PATH,CONFIG.get('Excel','Chemin_Excel')+ FICHIERS[y] ), index_col=None) 

def convertUTF(dataset):
    for col in dataset:
        dataset[col] = dataset[col].astype(str).str.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='replace')
    return dataset

#converting all data to utf8
for nom, valeur in DONNEES.items():
        DONNEES[nom] = convertUTF(valeur)

#insert into the db
engine = create_engine(INFOS_CONNECTION, encoding="utf-8", echo=True)
con = engine.connect()
con.execute("SET GLOBAL SQL_MODE='NO_ZERO_DATE';")
con.execute('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;')
con.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
con.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
con.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')

for k, v in DONNEES.items():
    v.to_sql(con=con, name=k.lower(), if_exists='append',index=False)
```

Here is my data, when i import in MySQL, NaT becomes 0000-00-00 (as string) and NaN "nan" (also as string...i also tried to replace the null by "NULL" but it stays as string... not real null sql value).

```
print(DONNEES['T_Liste******t'])

CodePersonnel PrenomEnfant NomEnfant DateNaissance DateDeces  Enfant***     Sexe  ClientPresent  Archiver
0            -------      -------    -------    1985-05-05       NaT              NaN     1              0         0
1            -------        -------   -------    1991-02-11       NaT            NaN     2              0         0
2            -------    -------    -------    1990-01-26       NaT             NaN     2              0         0
3            -------    -------    ------- 1982-11-23       NaT        NaN     2              0         0
4           -------       -------   -------   1985-06-07       NaT        NaN     1              0         0
...              ...          ...       ...           ...       ...
```

(i've replaced names by ------ by security)

Comment: Do you need utf8mb4?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Tried it ... (utf8mb4 and collation utf8mb4_general_ci)
Still get 'NaT' 'NaN' and '0000-00-00' values as string, not a real null.

Comment: Is there any case where python/pandas emits NULL?  NaN sounds like the interpretation of NULL for a FLOAT/DOUBLE; etc.